# Which type for boolean values is appropriate to use when writing a C library interface?

Tags: c, interface, boolean

When writing a C library to be called by other languages and probably compiled to multiple platforms, which type is the most appropriate one to represent boolean values?

I can not use C99 in the current project, but if I could, would C99s bool be appropriate?

**EDIT:** 
I'm leaning towards unsigned char or unsigned int. Is there any reason to explicitly specify signed or unsigned, does it help to avoid any ambiguities or pitfalls or should I simply use int?

But, when looking at some of the third party libraries I use and other threads about C, C++, Obj C it seems like most library and language designers have their own idea of what type is the best one to use for bools.

This is really not a problem now since this code is only compiled with one compiler for one platform, but it might be ported later.

Which is the best choice for boolean type to maximize portability?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When writing a C library to be called by other languages and probably compiled to multiple platforms, which type is the most appropriate one to represent boolean values?

Typically, you'll find that people just typedef it to `int`, because that's usually most efficient from a computation point-of-view (an `int` is usually the native type for the platform).  But really, any integer type would work; if you're particularly concerned about memory usage, then go with a `char`.

> I can not use C99 in the current project, but if I could, would C99s bool be appropriate?

Yes!

> I'm leaning towards unsigned char or unsigned int since the value unsigned zero probably has the same representation in most contexts?

I'm not sure how to answer this; why are you concerned about the underlying representation?

Comment: Thanx for a quick reply, I'll wait to accept the answer if someone might elaborate on this further. About the underlying representation, I'm thinking that choosing an explicitly unsigned type should be more reliable to avoid implicit signedness and perhaps prevent someone to pass an implicitly unsigned or signed type when the other was expected, am I perhaps being overly paranoid? Actually reading my own comment made me think I should just specify either signed or unsigned, not sure why I was concerned about unsigned being a better choice.

Comment: failed to edit the last comment, timed out (5 min), editing the question regarding signedness.